# DB Browser for SQLite encoding?

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am using DB Browser for SQLite to analyse CSV data and I am trying to run a simple query that seems to be returning an odd result:

```
select MIN(created_at1) from Table
```

The above query is returning "01/06/2017 00:22" as the result, but this is not the minimum date in this CSV. The minimum date is "23/05/2017 16:13". I suspect that DB Browser thinks my data is in US format so it thinks the result it's returning as minimum (01/06, 1 June) is actually 6 January. How can I let DB Browser "know" my data is in UK date format? I guess it's the encoding but not sure what to change it to (UTF-8 doesn't seem to fix the issue)..

Answer (score 1):

[There is no "date" data type in SQLite.](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype)

Dates are saved as strings. In order to be able to use functions like `MIN()`, it's your responsibility to choose a sane date format, i.e. one that does the right thing when sorted lexicographically.

The only sane date format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. (If you deal with time zones, use UTC plus a numeric offset.)